# EntityFramework: using a view to extend a table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'd like to use a view to add information to a table like this

```
public class PocoTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public partial class ImportStatingRecordError : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql(@"
CREATE VIEW PocoView
AS
    SELECT Id, ISNULL(l.InterestingValue, '?') AS InterestingValue
    FROM PocoTable t
        LEFT JOIN OtherTable o ON t.Id = o.PocoTableId
");
    }
}

public class PocoView : PocoTable
{
    public string InterestingValue { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<PocoTable> PocoTables { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PocoView> PocoViews { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PocoView>().ToView("PocoView").HasKey(z => new z.Id);
    }
}
```

But EntityFramework (core) isn't having any of it because:

> The entity type 'PocoView' cannot be mapped to a table because it is derived from 'PocoTable'. Only base entity types can be mapped to a table.

Can this be made to work? Or can I do this some other way?

Comment: You could use a Interface to define the Structure and implement ist to both classes. Then you can map the View-class and can Target both when using the Interface.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [HasBaseType(Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder.hasbasetype?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_EntityTypeBuilder_HasBaseType_System_Type_) method and pass `null` to let EF Core not treat `PocoTable` as base *entity* (part of [database inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance)) of `PocoView`, e.g.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PocoView>()
    .HasBaseType((Type)null) // <--
    .ToView("PocoView");
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
public abstract class PocoBase 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Table("PocoTable ")]
pubic class PocoTable : PocoBase {}

public class PocoView : PocoBase 
{
  public string InterestingValue { get; set; }
}
```

Which is better?

Comment: This always worked, and the idea is the same - share base **class** instead of base **entity**. There is no "better", since both approaches work and achieve the desired goal.