# Can I make entity framework to ignore inheritance?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to make Entity Framework ignore the fact class I'm using is derived from other class.

I have abstract-base class `Order` and derived classes `ShipOrder` & `MakeOrder`

`ShipOrder` and `MakeOrder` are saved into the same table via inheritance and discriminator field.

I want to make `OrderView` class which will be derived from `Order` and manually add properties of ShipOrder and MakeOrder to exact same representation of table in DB.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderView>().ToView("Orders");
```

this will work, but only when there is no inheritance and I copy fields from Order to OrderView Class (which I want to avoid). Is there a way to let entity framework know to ignore the fact OrderView is inherited from Order?

When I try to run the codebase with inherited OrderView from Order I get exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'OrderView' is part of a hierarchy, but does not have a discriminator value configured.
```

Comment: What is happening when you have the inheritance in place that `OrderView` is extending from `Order`? What are the problems that arise when using/defining the classes as you wrote in your question?

Comment: @Progman I updated question base on your comment

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to replicate the problem. The description isn't clear enough. An abstract base class should be OK, it's not clear why it isn't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61623102/entityframework-using-a-view-to-extend-a-table/61623592#61623592

Comment: @IvanStoev yes! that's exactly I was looking for. Thanks!