# Entity cannot be configured as keyless because it is a derived type

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have a Class `ApplicationUser` and a class `vwUserConfig`. `vwUserConfig` is a view in the database, and it has all columns of `ApplicationUser` including a few more.

I want, and need, `vwUserConfig` to inherit from `ApplicationUser`. But when I configure the view:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");
modelBuilder.Entity<VwUserConfig>().ToView("vwUserConfig");
```

I get an error indicating I cannot call `.HasNoKey()` since it inherits from `ApplicationUser`:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'VwUserConfig' cannot be configured as keyless because it is a derived type; the root type 'ApplicationUser' must be configured as keyless instead. If you did not intend for 'ApplicationUser' to be included in the model, ensure that it is not referenced by a DbSet property on your context, referenced in a configuration call to ModelBuilder in 'OnModelCreating', or referenced from a navigation on a type that is included in the model.

If I remove `.HasNoKey()`, I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Both 'VwUserConfig' and 'ApplicationUser' are mapped to the table 'AspNetUsers'. All the entity types in a hierarchy that don't have a discriminator must be mapped to different tables. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2130430 for more information.

Comment: Can you do what the error message suggests?  `the root type 'ApplicationUser' must be configured as keyless instead`

Comment: @RobertHarvey I cannot do that, ApplicationUser does have a key and has its own table.

Comment: The second error message says `All the entity types in a hierarchy that don't have a discriminator must be mapped to different tables`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is mapped to a different table. ApplicationUser is mapped to AspNetUsers, while vwUserConfig is mapped to vwUserConfig

Comment: The second error message also says `Both 'VwUserConfig' and 'ApplicationUser' are mapped to the table 'AspNetUsers'` -- Why does it think that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No idea, I've even explicity specified right above the VwUserConfig line that ApplicationUser is mapped to AspNetUsers (see edited question)

Comment: Can see some mentions in the documentation of EF "reverse engineering database views", with reference to `ToView`. (By no means very clearly documented, IMO). Which I think means it's "seeing through" the view to the underlying table, which is the same. If the view has all of the columns of the table, why does the table need to be mapped at all? Why not just have the view?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever because I still need the table for other reasons (i.e views cannot have primary keys). However, I found a hack which seems to circumvent what's happening, which I will post into an answer.

Comment: The problem is the entity inheritance, not table or view mapping. You need `HasBaseType((Type)null)` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61623102/entityframework-using-a-view-to-extend-a-table/61623592#61623592

Answer (score 0):

After looking into it a bit, I realized that for some reason, EF Core still thinks `VwUserConfig` should **still** be mapped to `AspNetUsers`, even though I'm calling `.ToView()`. To circumvent this, I had to do this hack:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<VwUserConfig>().ToTable("jcudncyd").ToView("vwUserConfig");
```

I had to assign it to a random, non-existing table for it to be un-mapped (?) to `AspNetUsers`. This seems like a bug.